# Prove that an octagon has a symmetry center

Tags: geometry

All the angles of a convex octagon are equal, and all of its sides have a rational length. How can I prove that such an octagon has a symmetry center?

First of all, I think we should start with finding the point. Then we can prove that it is a symmetry center. We can easily get the angle measure of each octagon angle: it will be equal to $135$ degrees. Maybe the symmetry point is the bisector intersection point?
Currently I do not understand where we should use the fact about rational sides and what would change if the sides were irrational. Maybe this fact should be used in the proof?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Comment: Thanks. I will be adding my thoughts about the problem. A symmetry center is a point through which a straight line passes two points on the edge of the octagon, at the same distance from the center to opposite sides. By the way, could you please send me the link?

Comment: Sure, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959

Comment: I don't think that's true.

Comment: Could you please give me a hint on what this point could be?

Comment: It must have to do with the fact that the sine and cosine of 135 degrees are irrational.  I think you should add up the vectors that you get by going once around the octagon, and see what you get.  Since you get back to where you started, what does that tell you?  (I haven't done this myself, it's just what I would try first.)

Comment: Actually, you don't have to go all the way around.  Adding up angles, you find opposite sides are parallel.  Now enclose the octagon in a rectangle by extending two pairs of opposite sides, and compute the sides of the rectangle.  We find from the rationality condition that opposite sides are equal.  That should make the rest easy, I think.

Comment: Just checking, is it the intersection point of diagonals in the rectangle?